# One compilation unit in Release, all others in Debug. MSVC

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++

The following code is not fast enough to run in real-time in a debug build, but is fast enough in a release build. So I though I'd just change the compilation options for just the cpp file it is in.

I tried the obvious /O2 and then /arch:AVX2 and then set all options under C++ > Optimization and C++ > Code Generation to be the same as the release build (excluding whole program optimization /GL).

But this didn't work so I'd like to know why.

Also, I've just run the debug build without the debugger so it's not that.

```cpp
inline uint8_t float32_to_unorm8(float in)
{
    return std::clamp(in, 0.f, 1.f) * std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max();
}

std::array<uint8_t, 4> kernel(float in)
{
    return { float32_to_unorm8(in / 951.f), float32_to_unorm8(in / 951.f),
        in == 0.f ? uint8_t(0) : std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max(), std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max() };
}

void DtwAligner::copy_to_upload()
{
    auto index = upload_write_sentinel;
    auto dest_span = upload_cpus[index % NUM_UPLOADS];

    for (auto i : ranges::views::ints(0u, ACCUMULATE_LENGTH))
    {
        auto source_span = accumulate_rows[(i + accumulate_index) % ACCUMULATE_LENGTH];
        std::transform(source_span.begin(), source_span.end(), dest_span.data() + i * UploadStride, &kernel);
    }
    upload_write_sentinel += 1;
}
```

Comment: Side note: the output of an optimizing compiler looks almost nothing like the input code. If your goal is to be able to step through the result with a debugger, expect the flow of the code to look borderline nonsensical.

Comment: You can compare all resulting options listed under `C++ -> Command Line`. Maybe it is `/D "_DEBUG"` vs `/D "NDEBUG"`, maybe something else.

Comment: @user4581301 I made a separate cpp file and applied the optimizations just to that file. I should be able to step through the rest of my codebase.

Comment: The command line switches look like Visual Studio. VS does a lot of neat stuff in their debug builds to help you spot bugs. They set blocks of memory to easy-to-spot canary values so you can pick off uninitialized variables, they add in extra tests, the library implementation is a bit slower because of even more tests. All sorts of fun in the debug builds.

Comment: @dewaffled thanks, I tried `#undef _DEBUG
#define NDEBUG
#include "pch.h"` with no luck

Comment: @user4581301 the bounds checking on `std::array/vector/span` is a lifesaver. I think I'd just reimplement the function in C now

Comment: @TomHuntington -- You forgot that the code that checks iterators will be on, regardless of those switches you have set.  That in itself is a big reason why debug builds are slower.  There are various `#define` macros that turn on/off iterator checking, but I would be wary of this since it may change the internals of some classes that may make them incompatible with the rest of your build.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can you turn them off for one compilation unit? I just rewrote the function in C (raw pointers) and the performance is still the same? So I don't know if that's the problem

Comment: @TomHuntington -- Like I said, if you, for example, manipulate a `std::string` from within the module you've done all of these optimizations to, and you then pass that string to a module that hasn't been optimized, you risk breakage due to the internals of `std::string` being different in both modules.  Maybe not, but I wouldn't chance it.

Comment: I'm not sure how easy it is to mix-n-match debug and release in Visual Studio. I'd probably start by making a debug library and link it to a release executable, but I've had nightmares in the past <expletive deleted>ing up MT, MTd, MD, MDd, etc...

Comment: @TomHuntington -- Let's ask you -- what's the high-level reason why the debug build is slow?  Is it the amount of data?  If so, maybe reduce the data set when debugging?  For example "the reason the debug build is slow because I am reading a million line text file", or something like that.  The "solution" would be to test against a smaller file.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks, for me the solution is to just write a compute shader.

Comment: In the future, if you want your `Debug` configuration to be the same as the `Release` configuration, then delete the `Debug` configuration from the `Configuration Manager`. Then create a new configuration and base it off of the `Release` configuration and just name the new configuration `Debug`

Comment: @WBuck the hope was to have just one compilation unit with the the `Release` configuration and the rest with `Debug`

Comment: I usually do the reverse if I have to debug a program with lots of input data: build it in release, debug it roughly to get an idea about the involved files, and then put `#pragma optimize ("", off)` at the top of each involved cpp file (below the includes), which are typically few. That way I can debug them properly while the rest of the code remains optimized.

Comment: Otherwise, the [`#pragma optimize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/optimize?view=msvc-170) macro can also be used to enable optimizations locally, eg in a debug build. But as others have noted, all the debug asserts and crosschecks in the standard library will still be there and slow down the code. Disabling them locally (eg. `#define NDEBUG`) is a bad idea because of possible ODR violations.

Comment: @Sedenion Thanks, but it didn't work. I have a feeling that this was auto vectorised (simd) in `Release` since my rewrite in c didn't work. I'd have to look though the disassembly to get to the bottom of this...